# Pytorch model dies with a java interrupted exception

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pytorch model that dies with an exception. I am running docker on a Mac.

```
    2021-11-22 09:58:25,083 [INFO ] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stdout MODEL_LOG - done saving hyperparameters
2021-11-22 09:58:25,162 [INFO ] W-9002-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stdout MODEL_LOG - saving hyperparameters
2021-11-22 09:58:25,185 [INFO ] W-9002-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stdout MODEL_LOG - done saving hyperparameters
2021-11-22 09:58:38,625 [INFO ] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Stopped Scanner - W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stderr
2021-11-22 09:58:38,626 [INFO ] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Stopped Scanner - W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stdout
2021-11-22 09:58:38,688 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-5-4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - 9001 Worker disconnected. WORKER_STARTED
2021-11-22 09:58:38,705 [DEBUG] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - System state is : WORKER_STARTED
2021-11-22 09:58:38,708 [DEBUG] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend worker monitoring thread interrupted or backend worker process died.
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2133)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:432)
        at org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:188)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021-11-22 09:58:38,765 [WARN ] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.BatchAggregator - Load model failed: deviceidentification, error: Worker died.
2021-11-22 09:58:38,768 [DEBUG] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 State change WORKER_STARTED -> WORKER_STOPPED
2021-11-22 09:58:38,798 [WARN ] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - terminateIOStreams() threadName=W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stderr
2021-11-22 09:58:38,798 [WARN ] W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - terminateIOStreams() threadName=W-9001-deviceidentification_ffda761820ab4a519ef598fb241e28d4-stdout
```

the top of the log file is

```
    2021-11-22 09:56:32,219 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager - Initializing plugins manager...
2021-11-22 09:56:32,511 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer -
Torchserve version: 0.4.2
TS Home: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Current directory: /home/model-server
Temp directory: /home/model-server/tmp
Number of GPUs: 0
Number of CPUs: 4
Max heap size: 498 M
Python executable: /usr/bin/python3
Config file: /home/model-server/config.properties
Inference address: http://0.0.0.0:8501
Management address: http://0.0.0.0:8081
Metrics address: http://127.0.0.1:8082
Model Store: /home/model-server/model-store
Initial Models: all
Log dir: /home/model-server/logs
Metrics dir: /home/model-server/logs
Netty threads: 32
Netty client threads: 0
Default workers per model: 4
Blacklist Regex: N/A
```

I have other pytorch models with identical Dockerfile and they run fine.

I see a lot of mentions of this error but none with solutions/workarounds

How can I debug this error?

Comment: We will need to see the `ts_log.log` to understand more about what is causing the issue.